# R: Using For Loop Variable in Function Declaration

Tags: r, closures

I would like to create a list of functions in R where values from a for loop are stored in the function definition. Here is an example:

```
init <- function(){
  mod <- list()
  for(i in 1:3){
    mod[[length(mod) + 1]] <- function(x) sum(i + x)
  }
  return(mod)
}

mod <- init()

mod[[1]](2) # 5 - but I want 3
mod[[2]](2) # 5 - but I want 4
```

In the above example, regardless of which function I call, `i` is always the last value in the for loop sequence, I understand this is the correct behavior.

I'm looking for something that achieves this:

```
mod[[1]] <- function(x) sum(1 + x)
mod[[2]] <- function(x) sum(2 + x)
mod[[3]] <- function(x) sum(3 + x)
```

Comment: Why? Seems convoluted. It sounds like you want to declare another variable like `const <-  2` before the loop, and use `sum(const + x)` instead. Still really confused...

Comment: I added an example of what i would like each function to look like. My actual use case is more conplicated. I'm just trying to understand how the scope works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly ensure `i` is evaluated at it's current value in the for loop by using `force`.

```
init <- function(){
  mod <- list()
  f_gen = function(i) {
    force(i)
    return(function(x) sum(i + x))
  }
  for(i in 1:3){
    mod[[i]] <- f_gen(i)
  }
  return(mod)
}

mod <- init()

mod[[1]](2)
# [1] 3
mod[[2]](2)
# [1] 4
```

More details are in the [Functions/Lazy Evaluation subsection of Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html). Also see `?force`, of course. Your example is *fairly* similar to the examples given in `?force`.

Using a single-function generator function (`f_gen` in my code above) seems to make more sense than a list-of-functions generator function. Using my `f_gen` your code code be simplified:

```
f_gen = function(i) {
        force(i)
        return(function(x) sum(i + x))
}
mod2 <- lapply(1:3, f_gen)

mod2[[1]](2)
# [1] 3
mod2[[2]](2)
# [1] 4

## or alternately
mod3 = list()
for (i in 1:3) mod3[[i]] <- f_gen(i)
mod3[[1]](2)
mod3[[2]](2)
```